# LaTex \multirow overlaping with next row

Tags: tables, multirow

Im having an issue with my code. Im new to latex and I used a table editor to generate the codes for me. I would like to make a table like the one below however the rows end up overlapping (also shown below).

[image: What I want the table to be]

[image: The resulting table]

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \caption{FMEA analysis on the possible failure modes of the fan blade.}
    \label{tab:FMEA}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{clclcclc} 
    \hline
    Failure Mode               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Effects}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & S                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Causes}                                                                              & P                      & D                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Design Considerations}                                                                                                & RPN  \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Fatigue}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Fan will be inoperable until fan blade replaced.\\ \\ 2) Failure during operation may \\ lead to injuries or damages\\ to other equipment. \\\end{tabular}}                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{9} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Alternating load cycles \\ when RPM is decreased\\ or increased\end{tabular} & 8                      & 6                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1)Reduce the frequency of RPM change and reduce deformation\\ during loading. \\\end{tabular}                 & 432  \\
                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}High temperature induces \\ propagation of microcracks\end{tabular}          & 9                      & 1                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) Operating temperature (400 C) must not\\ be higher than 0.3$T_m$ of \\ selected material. \\\end{tabular}  & 81   \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Corrosion} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Surface imperfections caused by corrosion increase drag,\\ reducing the fan efficiency.\\ \\ 2) Reduces structural integrity\\ of the fan blades which increases\\ chances of premature failure.~\\\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Abrasion and degradation\\ of anti-corrosion coating\end{tabular}            & 10                     & 2                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Select a more corrosion-resistant\\ material to reduce reliance\\ on anti-corrosion coatings.\end{tabular} & 120  \\
                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & Pitting corrosion                                                                                       & 7                      & 6                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) Avoid passive metals for the\\ construction of the blade.\end{tabular}                                     & 252  \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Creep}     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) May result in loss of performance\\ if blade is deformed,\\ or injuries if catastrophic\\ failure occurs. \\ 2) More frequent blade replacements\\ would increase operating costs \\\end{tabular}}                & \multirow{2}{*}{9} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Constant loading of the\\ fan blades\end{tabular}                            & 9                      & 4                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Finite element analysis may help\\ obtain the most optimal blade\\ geometry.\end{tabular}                  & 324  \\
                               &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}High temperature increases\\ dislocation mobility\end{tabular}               & 9                      & 1                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) The operating temperature\\ (400 C) must not \\ exceed 0.5$T_m$ of the material\end{tabular}               & 81   \\ 
    \hline
    Impact                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Damage surface and reduce\\aerodynamic efficiency of the blade. \\ 2) A large object may cause deformation\\ or complete failure of the blade, deeming\\ the machine inoperable. \\\end{tabular}                                  & 9                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ingestion of solid objects\\ into the fan \end{tabular}                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The blades must be inspected\\ frequently for surface damage\\ or any deformation. \end{tabular}              & 180  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table*}
```

Comment: @dolandduck :) have a look at the answer below and welcome to the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be best to let LaTeX do the line breaking, and therefore use `p{...}` columns for the multiline texts. This makes the code much simpler. The other columns can be positioned with `\multirow`, but they need some manual tuning (using the actual number of lines in the other columns as `nrows` in `\multirow`). So here is my solution. (I use `makecell` only to get "gapes".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \caption{FMEA analysis on the possible failure modes of the fan blade.}
        \label{tab:FMEA}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells

            \begin{tabular}{ccp{5cm}cp{4cm}ccp{6cm}c} 
% 1 header
\toprule
1                  & Failure mode               & Effects                                                                                                                                                               & S                  & Causes                                                                                 & P                   & D                  & Design Considerations                                                                                                                                       & RPN                  \\
 \midrule 
\multirow{2}{*}{2}                  & \multirow{7}{*}{Fatigue}   & 1) Fan will be inoperable until fan blade replaced.                                                                                                                   & \multirow{7}{*}{9} & Alternating load cycles when RPM is decreased or increased                             & 8                   & 6                  & 1) Reduce the frequency of RPM change and reduce deformation during loading.                                                                                & \multirow{2}{*}{432}                  \\
\multirow{3}{*}{3}                  &                            & 2) Failure during operation may lead to injuries or damages to other equipment.                                                                                       &                    & High temperature induces propagation of microcracks                                    & 9                   & 1                  & 2) Operating temperature (400 C) must not be higher than 0.3$T_m$ of selected material.                                                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{81}                   \\
\midrule
4                  & \multirow{7}{*}{Corrosion} & 1) Surface imperfections caused by corrosion increase drag, reducing the fan efficiency.                                                                              & \multirow{7}{*}{6} & Abrasion and degradation of anti-corrosion coating                                     & 10                  & 2                  & 1) Select a more corrosion-resistant material to reduce reliance on anti-corrosion coatings.                                                                & 120                  \\
5                  &                            & 2) Reduces structural integrity of the fan blades which increases chances of premature failure.                                                                       &                    & Pitting Corrosion                                                                      & 7                   & 6                  & 2) Avoid passive metals for the construction of the blade.                                                                                                  & 252                  \\
 \midrule
6                  & \multirow{8}{*}{Creep}     & 1) May result in loss of performance if blade is deformed, or injuries if catastrophic failure occurs.                                                                & \multirow{8}{*}{9} & Constant loading of the fan blades                                                     & 9                   & 4                  & 1) Finite element analysis may help obtain the most optimal blade geometry.                                                                                 & 324                  \\
7                  &                            & 2) More frequent blade replacements would increase operating costs                                                                                                    &                    & High temperature increases dislocation mobility          & 9                   & 1                  & 2) The operating temperature (400 C) must not exceed 0.5$T_m$ of the material                                                                               & 81                   \\
 \midrule
\multirow{8}{*}{8} & \multirow{8}{*}{Impact}    & 1) Damage surface and reduce aerodynamic efficiency of the blade.                                                                      & \multirow{8}{*}{9} & \multirow{8}{=}{Ingestion of solid objects into the fan} & \multirow{8}{*}{10} & \multirow{8}{*}{2} & \multirow{8}{=}{The blades must be inspected frequently for surface damage or any deformation.} & \multirow{8}{*}{180} \\
                   &                            & 2) A large object may cause deformation or complete failure of the blade, deeming the machine inoperable. &                    &                                                                                        &                     &                    &                                                                                                                                                             &                      \\ 
 \bottomrule

            \end{tabular}
%       }
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Pieter!

Thank you so much! You just saved my undergrad career! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code in the paragraph title `Corrosion` and `Creep` with package `makecell` which is better than creating tables within the tabular environ -- have look -- also using package `booktabs` and using `toprule`, `midrule`, `bottomrule` gives better spacing -- you can follow the same for the rest of the table -- will give you the desired result

```
\makecell[l]{1) Surface imperfections caused by corrosion increase drag,\\ reducing the fan efficiency.\\ 2) Reduces structural integrity\\ of the fan blades which increases\\ chances of premature failure.~\\}
```

[image]

Partial code changed MWE -- remaining left for the OP

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{1\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \caption{FMEA analysis on the possible failure modes of the fan blade.}
        \label{tab:FMEA}
%       \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{clclcclc} 
                \toprule
                Failure Mode               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Effects}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     & S                  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Causes}                                                                              & P                      & D                     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Design Considerations}                                                                                                & RPN  \\ 
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{*}{Fatigue}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Fan will be inoperable until fan blade replaced.\\ \\ 2) Failure during operation may \\ lead to injuries or damages\\ to other equipment. \\\end{tabular}}                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{9} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Alternating load cycles \\ when RPM is decreased\\ or increased\end{tabular} & 8                      & 6                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1)Reduce the frequency of RPM change and reduce deformation\\ during loading. \\\end{tabular}                 & 432  \\
                &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}High temperature induces \\ propagation of microcracks\end{tabular}          & 9                      & 1                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) Operating temperature (400 C) must not\\ be higher than 0.3$T_m$ of \\ selected material. \\\end{tabular}  & 81   \\ 
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{*}{Corrosion} & \makecell[l]{1) Surface imperfections caused by corrosion increase drag,\\ reducing the fan efficiency.\\ 2) Reduces structural integrity\\ of the fan blades which increases\\ chances of premature failure.~\\} & \multirow{2}{*}{6} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Abrasion and degradation\\ of anti-corrosion coating\end{tabular}            & 10                     & 2                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Select a more corrosion-resistant\\ material to reduce reliance\\ on anti-corrosion coatings.\end{tabular} & 120  \\
                &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & Pitting corrosion                                                                                       & 7                      & 6                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) Avoid passive metals for the\\ construction of the blade.\end{tabular}                                     & 252  \\ 
                \midrule
                \multirow{2}{*}{Creep}     & \makecell[l]{1) May result in loss of performance\\ if blade is deformed,\\ or injuries if catastrophic\\ failure occurs. \\ 2) More frequent blade replacements\\ would increase operating costs \\}                & \multirow{2}{*}{9} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Constant loading of the\\ fan blades\end{tabular}                            & 9                      & 4                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Finite element analysis may help\\ obtain the most optimal blade\\ geometry.\end{tabular}                  & 324  \\
                &                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 &                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}High temperature increases\\ dislocation mobility\end{tabular}               & 9                      & 1                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2) The operating temperature\\ (400 C) must not \\ exceed 0.5$T_m$ of the material\end{tabular}               & 81   \\ 
                \midrule
                Impact                     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1) Damage surface and reduce\\aerodynamic efficiency of the blade. \\ 2) A large object may cause deformation\\ or complete failure of the blade, deeming\\ the machine inoperable. \\\end{tabular}                                  & 9                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ingestion of solid objects\\ into the fan \end{tabular}                      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The blades must be inspected\\ frequently for surface damage\\ or any deformation. \end{tabular}              & 180  \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
%       }
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!